# Как узнать ID только что добавленного элемента в RedBean?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, redbeanphp

Всем привет.
У меня такая проблема. Мне нужно добавлять запись в БД и при этом сразу узнавать какое значение `ID` ей будет дано по автоинкременту в БД.

```
if (isset($data['send_album'])) {

    $tr = R::dispense('lyrics');
    $tr->name = "newName";
    R::store($tr);
}
```

Для работы использую RedBeanPHP, поэтому не могу понять как это реализовать его средствами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечаю на свой же вопрос. Для того чтобы отобразить через `RedBean` `ID` последнего элемента в БД нужно просто обратиться к этой сущности и его `ID` после метода `R::store()`

```
   $newAlbum = R::dispense('albums');
   $newAlbum->album_name = "new";
   R::store($newAlbum);
   echo $newAlbum->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто
$tr есть твоя запись,
спроси у неё id
после
R::store($tr);
Примерно так
$tr["id"];

```
if (isset($data['send_album'])) {

    $tr = R::dispense('lyrics');
    $tr->name = "newName";
    R::store($tr);
    echo $tr["id"]; //Решение проблемы
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$oper = R::dispense('certificat');
$oper->loginuser  = $login;
$oper->email      = $email;
$oper->phone      = $phone;    
$id = R::store($oper);

$idnew = R::getInsertID();   // получаем ID новой записи...

echo $idnew;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

```
$id = R::store($tr);
```

Не имел дело с RedBeanPHP, но ORM обычно возвращает что-то, стоит проверить.

Comment: Такой способ не работает.